# Issue while compiling smart contract - eosio.cdt

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt, compilation, eosio-cpp

I have installed `eosio.cdt` in Ubuntu system by using commands from EOS Developers Portal

```
wget https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/releases/download/v1.4.1/eosio.cdt-1.4.1.x86_64.deb
sudo apt install ./eosio.cdt-1.4.1.x86_64.deb
```

After that I have tried to compile the hello contract using eosio-cpp tool

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

class [[eosio::contract("hello")]] hello : public contract {
  public:
      using contract::contract;

      [[eosio::action]]
      void hi( name user ) {
         print( "Hello, ", user);
      }
};

EOSIO_DISPATCH( hello, (hi))
```

I have tried to compile the code using

```
eosio-cpp -o hello.wasm hello.cpp --abigen
```

But it returns

```
/usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.4.1/bin/clang-7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.4.1/bin/clang-7)
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/issues/285 Have a look at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue by using below commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade libstdc++6
```

Comment: still getting the same error, i tried installing libstdc++6 and update too.

Comment: please check the edited answer @cjcoders